# shady-render.ts:46 Uncaught TypeError: result.getTemplateElement is not a function

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

When I try executing Polymer element locally,I am using polymer 3 and my HTML structure is HTML5.

The counter-comp tag is added in my  html file.

```
import {LitElement} from "@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js"
class CounterComp extends LitElement{
constructor(){
    super()
}
static get properties(){
   return{
       color:String,
       background :String,
       fontweight: String
   }
}
_render({color,background,fontweight}){
    return html`
    <style>
    .title{
    background:$(background) ;
    color: $(color);
    font-weight:$(fontweight) ;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    }

</style>
<div class = "title">"This is in div tag with class title"</div>
    `;
    }
}
customElements.define("counter-comp",CounterComp);



<counter-comp color="green" background="blue" font-weight="355">
</counter-comp>
```

> shady-render.ts:46 Uncaught TypeError: result.getTemplateElement is
>   not a  function  at result (shady-render.ts:46)  at render
>   (shady-render.ts:130)  at HTMLElement._applyRender
>   (lit-element.ts:232)  at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged
>   (lit-element.ts:183)  at HTMLElement._flushProperties
>   (properties-changed.js?module:335)  at HTMLElement._flushProperties
>   (lit-element.ts:194) at HTMLElement.ready 
>   (properties-changed.js?module:179) at HTMLElement.ready
>   (lit-element.ts:107)  at HTMLElement._enableProperties
>   (properties-changed.js?module:315)  at HTMLElement.connectedCallback
>   (properties-mixin.js?module:200)

I am getting the above Error please check and help to get this solved.

Thanks

Comment: I found the solution to myself guys.. we should add html in import {LitElement,html} from "@polymer/lit-element"

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import {LitElement} from "@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js"
```

use:

```
import {LitElement, html} from "@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js"
```